# split up string with delimiter only using basic language(if,for,while etc)

Tags: javascript

i have the function:

```
//this function takes two params, a string and then the delimiter where the string is to be split up
function substringSplit(str, del){
    var str;
    var del;
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(!str[i]==del){
            var res = str[i];
            console.log(res);
        }
    }
```

and what i am trying to achieve is splitting up a string e.g "the house is there" with a delimiter i.e " ", however my code isnt doing this properly!

does any one have any suggestions?

ps the idea is to not use another functions i.e split().

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `str` and `del`? Also: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: evidently i am new to js haha

Comment: the idea is to not use split() thats the point

Comment: `!str[i]==del` --> `!(str[i]==del)`

Comment: @DAXaholic → `str[i]!=del`

Comment: @Biffen excellent link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code would be printing out one by one all the characters that are not equal to the delimiter.
So if my call was:

```
substringSplit("hi tom"," ");
```

Your program would print:

```
h
i
t
o
m
```

this could be a possible algorithm to achieve what you want:

```
function substringSplit(str, del){
    var splitArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        var newWord = "";
        while(str[i]!=del && i < str.length) {
            newWord += str[i];
            i++;
        }
        splitArray.push(newWord);
    }
    return splitArray;
}
```

I have not tested boundary conditions, so don't take this as perfect but maybe just a base to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to build an array:

```js
function split(str, del) {
  var res = [], i, prev = 0;
  while (~(i = str.indexOf(del, prev))) {
    res.push(str.slice(prev, i));
    prev = i + del.length;
  }
  res.push(str.slice(prev));
  return res;
}

console.log(split("the house is there", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small code to make it work. i added `if (values[valuesIndex])` to take the case of having more than one space next to one another.

```js
function mySplit(str, deli) {
  var repeat = str.length;
  var valuesIndex = 0;
  var values = [];

  while (repeat) {
    var char = str[0];
    if (char !== deli) {
      values[valuesIndex] = values[valuesIndex] || "";
      values[valuesIndex] += char;
    } else if (values[valuesIndex]) {
      valuesIndex++;
    }
    str = str.substring(1);
    repeat--;
  }
  return values;
}

console.log(mySplit("the house is there", " "));
```